# Selenium won't load full website with Chrome or any other browser

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

When I open this website https://marketchameleon.com/Reports/PremarketTrading/ using Selenium with Chrome or Firefox the tables do not load, but if I open the website via the normal way with Chrome the content loads.

This is my code to open a browser:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

#driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://marketchameleon.com/Reports/PremarketTrading/')
timeout =3
```

Can someone point me to the right direction? I am new to Python.

Answer (score -1):

First you will have to install Selenium driver in your system. Check out this link and try again.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0vsswJooDe0